# Multinominal logistics regression

Tags: regression, self-study, spss

I need help with following table
Regarding the outcome (pcr 3) is there a way to know its P-value ??

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: What is PCR? Polymerase chain reaction? Is this table summarizing two quantitative polymerase chain reaction models to to data?

Comment: The column "Sig." probably is denoted p-values. You cannot recover the p-values from inequalities such as $< 0.001$ alone.

Comment: @Galen No, but you *can* compute the p-value from the estimate "B" and its standard error "Std. Error."  However, there's something strange about these results: its p-values don't look correct.  They don't match what one would compute with either a Student t distribution or a Normal distribution.  Welcome to CV, Hala.  What can you tell us about the source of this table and how it was produced?

Comment: The table reports a value $\hat \beta = 21.653$ along with $\exp \hat \beta = 2532575249.126$. Assuming $\exp$ is the exponential function in the usual sense, the correct exponentiation to the same number of digits is $\exp \hat \beta = 2533835500.985$, so these two numbers contradict each other to a surprising number of figures. This is notwithstanding a proper consideration of the number of significant figures.